# CSS Grid - Formatting rows and column for responsive screens

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

Guys, I'm trying to develop the below layout. Is that possible with css grid? I'm adding whatever I have tried and still trying to achieve the desired result with spanning the rows and changing the order of the columns. any helps would be appreciated.

Note: I want the item-content to be spanned with all rows in second column. basically it works as tab in desktop and as accordion in mobile screen.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">item-1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">item-2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">item-3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">item-4</div>
  <div class="item item-content-1">item-content-1</div>
  <div class="item item-content-2">item-content-2</div>
  <div class="item item-content-3">item-content-3</div>
  <div class="item item-content-4">item-content-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer: [Revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/0mhsq6w2/37/)
 I think it work for you.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="item item-1 order1">item-1</div>
 <div class="item item-2 order2">item-2</div>
 <div class="item item-3 order3">item-3</div>
 <div class="item item-4 order4">item-4</div>
 <div class="item item-content-1 order1 active">item-content-1</div>
 <div class="item item-content-2 order2 ">item-content-2</div>
 <div class="item item-content-3 order3">item-content-3</div>
 <div class="item item-content-4 order4">item-content-4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .item {
    min-height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #333;
  }

  .item[class*="item-content-"] {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .item[class*="item-content-"].active {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    display: block;
  }

  @media (max-width:767px) {
    .order1 {
      order: 1;
    }
    .order2 {
      order: 2;
    }
    .order3 {
      order: 3;
    }
    .order4 {
      order: 4;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: stretch;
    }
    .item[class*="item-content-"] {
      background-color: goldenrod;
    }
    .item {
      height: 50px;
    }
    .item[class*="item-content-"].active {
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

You can use CSS `order` property. try it
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/6njLd9vk/5/)

> [The order CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or
>   grid container.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1 order1">item-1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 order2">item-2</div>
  <div class="item item-3 order3">item-3</div>
  <div class="item item-4 order4">item-4</div>
  <div class="item item-content-1 order1">item-content-1</div>
  <div class="item item-content-2 order2">item-content-2</div>
  <div class="item item-content-3 order3">item-content-3</div>
  <div class="item item-content-4 order4">item-content-4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.order1 {
  order: 1;
}

.order2 {
  order: 2;
}

.order3 {
  order: 3;
}

.order4 {
  order: 4;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Comment: ,I appreciate your effort but the item content takes full height of the container and other contents should be hidden..

Comment: Do you need accordion in small view?

Comment: yes, but don't worry about accordion for now. I just need to format the layout in that manner.

Comment: @VivekrajKR try it https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/0mhsq6w2/37/ ,I have updated it in above answer also

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible using a media query and column flow.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item[class*="item-content-"] {
  grid-column: 2;
  background: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .item[class*="item-content-"] {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .item-2 {
    grid-row-start: 6;
  }
  .item-3 {
    grid-row-start: 7;
  }
  .item-4 {
    grid-row-start: 8;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">item-1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">item-2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">item-3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">item-4</div>
  <div class="item item-content-1">item-content-1</div>
  <div class="item item-content-2">item-content-2</div>
  <div class="item item-content-3">item-content-3</div>
  <div class="item item-content-4">item-content-4</div>
</div>
```

Per the update (assuming there is only a single `.item-content` div

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item-content-1 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  background: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .item-content-1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">item-1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">item-2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">item-3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">item-4</div>
  <div class="item item-content-1">item-content-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as you can see in the sketch I want the item-content-1 to be spanned with rest of the rows. I have updated the question little bit for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: So where are the other `.item-content` divs?

Comment: Other .item-content divs will be hidden.